# Change width of mosaic layout to be 50% / 50%

Tags: css

I would like the images in this layout to each take up 50% of the page.
Right now the split is 2/3 for the large image and 1/3 for the 2 smaller images.

Images are here:

https://www.joshungerdesign.com/packed

I can make the large image take up 50% by using this:

```
.tweak-index-gallery-layout-packed [data-index-gallery-images='3'] 
.Index-gallery-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
width: 50%;}
```

I don't know how to make the small images extend to the right side once the large image width is changed.

Comment: Please put your HTML in the question itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just write basic code, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.Index-gallery-inner {
  background-color: #fff;      
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.Index-gallery-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 50%;
}

.Index-gallery-item:nth-child(2),
.Index-gallery-item:nth-child(3){
  height: 250px;
  width: 50%;
}

.Index-gallery-item-inner {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Index-gallery-item-image {
  background-color: white !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="Index-gallery-inner clear">
  <div class="Index-gallery-item">
    <div class="Index-gallery-item-inner"></div>
  </div>    
  <div class="Index-gallery-item">
    <div class="Index-gallery-item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Index-gallery-item">
    <div class="Index-gallery-item-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this be applied to the selectors on the site ie.    @Hassan Siddiqui

Comment: First i have to check HTML structure. can you share any working example or link? Thanks

Comment: the link is here.  https://www.joshungerdesign.com/packed . I understand it can be built from html but trying to modify this existing structure so someone can update later easily but they want the 50 / 50 layout.

Comment: I just update the above code snippet according to the required structure. Thanks

Comment: this seems to be really close! i updated to 50% on both sides.  The only thing I'm not seeing now is the padding.  Trying to work on that @ Hassan Siddiqui

Comment: do you know how to achieve the white borders?  Thats the only thing still missing.

Comment: White Background added in above snippet. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191120/discussion-between-junger-and-hassan-siddiqui).